# How could git reset --soft reset last commit without touching index file?

Tags: git, git-reset, git-add

This might be a noob question.

Suppose I have a Git repo which already have some files in the staged area by using git add. and then I do a `git reset --soft @~`

I am happy to see some files I committed last time are put into staged area now.

But how? I check `.git` folder. the only thing changed are ref of current branch. and one "ORIG_HEAD" which I think is not relevant. the most suspicious index file is not touched at all. and also can anyone tell me how to view the content of it?

So how could git do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In its simplest form,<sup>1</sup> `git reset` does two things:

- move the current branch, and/or
- undo things in the index

To understand how and why this works and what it does, you need to know how commits work and how the index works, at least at a relatively high level.  These are closely tied together anyway.

#### commits, trees, and blobs

First, a *commit* is simply a repository object of type "commit", which has as its data, the commit message and some other information (tree, parents, author, and committer):

```
$ git cat-file -p 5f95c9f850b19b368c43ae399cc831b17a26a5ac
tree 972825cf23ba10bc49e81289f628e06ad44044ff
parent 9c8ce7397bac108f83d77dfd96786edb28937511
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1392406504 -0800
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1392406504 -0800

Git 1.9.0

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

This commit is part of the source to git (it's the commit for git version 1.9.0).  As with all repository objects, its name is a 40-hex-character SHA-1 value.

The *working directory* for a commit is determined by the `tree`, which is yet another git object, so it has another SHA-1 name.  The output from `git cat-file -p 972825cf23ba10bc49e81289f628e06ad44044ff` is too long to include entirely but it starts with:

```
100644 blob 5e98806c6cc246acef5f539ae191710a0c06ad3f    .gitattributes
100644 blob b5f9defed37c43b2c6075d7065c8cbae2b1797e1    .gitignore
100644 blob 11057cbcdf4c9f814189bdbf0a17980825da194c    .mailmap
100644 blob 536e55524db72bd2acf175208aef4f3dfc148d42    COPYING
040000 tree 47fca99809b19aeac94aed024d64e6e6d759207d    Documentation
100755 blob 2b97352dd3b113b46bbd53248315ab91f0a9356b    GIT-VERSION-GEN
```

These `blob` entries are all the files (and sub-directories, for each `tree`; those have more `blob`s) that make up the source to git.  Each `blob` has a unique SHA-1 ID, based on the contents of the file.  The `tree` keeps a list of the file's "mode" (really just its `x` bit—these modes are all `100644` and `100755`) and file-name along with the SHA-1 name of the blob-object in the repository.  (Other modes, like the `040000` seen above, keep track of sub-trees, symbolic links, and submodules.  It's only blobs that are restricted to `100644` and `100755`.)

Every git repository object is read-only.  The commit whose ID is `5f95c9f...` will never change.  It will always have as its (single) `tree` the ID `972825c...`.  The file whose ID is `536e555...` is always that particular version of the file `COPYING`.  If the file is updated, a new, different blob with new, different SHA-1 goes in.

#### the index

Git's "index" (also called the "staging area" and sometimes the "cache") is a poorly-documented file that, in essence, represents "what will go in the next commit".

Unlike repository objects, the index is quite write-able.  To make "the next commit" have something different, git adds or removes entries from the index.  For instance, to update the file named `COPYING`, you would—after editing it—run `git add COPYING`.  This would take the new contents of the file `COPYING` and copy them into the repository (where they will eventually live forever),<sup>2</sup> computing an SHA-1 "true name" for the result.  This new SHA-1 then goes into the index (along with the mode and the name `COPYING`—basically, everything needed to make a commit).

#### making commits

Because the index has everything prepared like this, it's pretty easy to make a new commit.  All the correct `blob`s are already in the repository.  Git only needs to turn the index into some `tree` object(s), write those into the repository, get the final SHA-1 of the newest top-level `tree`, and write a new `commit` object.  The new commit will have the following properties:

- the `tree` is whatever gets written based on the index
- the `parent` is whatever is in `HEAD` now (more or less—there's some fiddling around with multiple parents when making merge commits)
- the `author` and `committer` and these dates are taken from the current time and your git configuration `user.name` and `user.email`, or from arguments (`--author`) or environment variables if those are set to override things
- the message is whatever you edit in as a commit message, or give as the `-m` parameter.

So git writes that commit, which produces a new, unique SHA-1.  It then writes that SHA-1 itself somewhere.

#### branches and `HEAD`

If you're "on branch `master`", as `git status` would say, that means the file `.git/HEAD` contains the literal string `ref: refs/heads/master`.  This is what git calls an "indirect reference": a reference that just says "go find another reference, here's the name."  Usually you are on some branch, and `HEAD` is an indirect reference to that branch.

The branch itself can be stored in several different ways, but the simplest is another file in `.git`, in this case, the file `.git/refs/heads/master`.  If that file exists and you read it, it will contain an SHA-1 like `5f95c9f850b19b368c43ae399cc831b17a26a5ac`.  That's the current commit, and is how git knows which commit you're "on", just like the `ref: refs/heads/master` is how git knows that you're on branch `master`.

To make a *new* commit, git writes the commit as described above, which produces a new unique SHA-1.  Then, since you're on branch `master`, git simply writes the new commit-ID into `.git/refs/heads/master`, and now you're on the new commit, which is the tip of branch `master`.

You can also have a "detached HEAD", which—despite sounding like something from the French Revolution—just means that `HEAD` is *not* an indirect reference.  Instead, `HEAD` contains a raw SHA-1.  In this case, to make a new commit, git makes the commit the same way as before, but instead of updating `.git/refs/heads/master`, it writes the new commit-ID right into `HEAD`.

### git reset

So, with all that in mind, let's look concretely at what `git reset` does.

If you do a `--soft` reset, git leaves the index completely untouched.  This means it only updates the current branch.

To update the current branch, git does the same thing as when making a new commit: it finds which branch `HEAD` indirects to, and writes a new SHA-1 into that reference.  If `HEAD` points to `master`, this only needs to write a new SHA-1 into `.git/refs/heads/master`.

The SHA-1 that git writes is the one you supply on the command line:

```
git reset --soft @~   # @~ means @~1, which means HEAD~1, aka HEAD^
```

You can see what the SHA-1 will be by running `git rev-parse` (for a `HEAD`-relative ref, you must do this *before* the `reset` changes `HEAD`, of course):

```
$ git rev-parse @~
9c8ce7397bac108f83d77dfd96786edb28937511
```

If you tell `git reset` to use `--mixed`, it *also* updates the index.  The things it puts into the index come from the commit SHA-1 it will write into the branch:

```
$ git reset --mixed HEAD -- COPYING
```

Here, by telling it to change the `HEAD` to `HEAD`, you get reset to move the branch no distance at all from where it used to be, so the branch does not get updated after all; but the `-- COPYING` says "extract the SHA-1 for file `COPYING` from the target revision `HEAD`, and put that SHA-1 into the index for the file `COPYING`."  So this means that the next commit *won't* have changes to file COPYING, because we've put the old SHA-1 back into the index.

If you tell `git reset` to use `--hard`, it *also* updates the working directory (it's already updating the branch and the index).  It does this by getting the actual file (or files) contents out of the repository (looking them up from the unique blob SHA-1s), and overwriting the work-directory version.  If you haven't `git add`-ed and `git commit`-ed those work-directory versions, this means the changes are gone.  (If you *did* `git add`, they're in the repository, but if you have not done a `git commit` they're eligible for garbage collection—see footnote.)

Since you used `--soft`, you suppressed changes to the index, so the only thing `git reset` could do is change the contents of the branch tip file, `.git/refs/heads/master`.

---

<sup>1</sup>`git reset` used to have just these three operating modes.  It now has `--merge` and `--keep`, plus `--patch`, that do more than the simple cases.  It's kind of like the Monty Python skit about the Spanish Inquisition: "Our three modes are soft, mixed, hard, and merge. ... *Four!*  Our *four* modes are soft, mixed, hard, merge, and keep..."

<sup>2</sup>Objects in the repository "live forever" with one very large exception: an *unreferenced* object, one that `git fsck` shows as `dangling`, is a candidate for garbage collection.  Unreferenced blobs, commits, and so on are perfectly normal.  They sit around occupying disk space (usually very little: objects are stored compressed) so that you can recover things, and so that they can be collected and discarded all at once later if and when git thinks it's a good idea to clean up.

Objects are "referenced" (and therefore live forever) when some external label—a branch name, a tag, `HEAD`, or whatever—points to them directly or indirectly.  A branch name points to the tip-most commit on that branch.  That commit points to its tree, which points to any sub-trees and blobs, so all of those remain forever; and that commit points to its parent commit(s), so those parents remain forever.  Each parent commit points in turn to its own parents, and those also remain forever.

A commit becomes *un*-referenced when you move the branch label away from it:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- HEAD=master
```

Here `master` (our current branch) points to `C`, `C` to `B`, and `B` to `A`.  But if we:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
```

we make `master` point to `B`, which points to `A`.  Commit `C` is now *unreferenced:* it has been abandoned, and eventually it will be garbage-collected, along with its tree and any sub-trees and blobs.  Similar events occur with, e.g., `git commit --amend`, which does a soft-reset-and-new-commit, making a new commit `D` that points to `B`, and having `master` point to `D`:

```
A - B - D   <-- HEAD=master
      \
        C   [abandoned]
```

The `rebase` operation copies and then abandons entire sequences of commits, generating a lot of candidate objects for garbage-collection.  This is why dangling objects are normal.

Comment: I guess I didn't state my question clearly. My question was before I use git reset --soft, I have some files already in the index (staged area), and after I used git reset --soft. more files are added into index. and obviously index is not touched at all. so how could index now changed without being touched?

Comment: It isn't (changed).  The index *still* contains "the next commit".  If you mean "why is the output of `git status` different", it's because `git status` compares the current (`HEAD`) commit against the index.  (And also against the work tree, but let's ignore that for now...)  You changed the `HEAD` commit, so the comparison result is different.

Comment: Thanks. so index already have been filled with files from latest commit after branch checked out. that's the part I didn't understand clearly I guess. And `git add` add some more files into index file. and I used `git reset` moved the `HEAD` so delta now become visible. But if index already have those files from latest commit. I still have a question, How could git quickly use index to create next commit? should Git first compare it with latest commit so files from latest commit excluded from next commit. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, no, that's where git is different from most other revision systems: a new commit stores *every file*.  However, if the SHA-1s are unchanged, it's not another *copy* of every file, it's the *same* copy.  Remember, the index contains SHA-1s (for every file).  If you make a new commit with the same index (`git commit --allow-empty`), the `tree` for the new commit is *the same* as the tree for the previous commit.  The only extra space needed is for the new commit itself.  No compares are required, nor done, for `--allow-empty`.  Compares are done only when asked-for, to see what's different.

Comment: I understand now. for record. `git ls-files -s` shows what's in the stage area. it's indeed a snapshot contains every files committed or modified. so git status will compare it with HEAD to show the delta. delta changed after git reset --soft is just because HEAD changed. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The index file is pure metadata, showing what's been staged and its filesystem stats.  When you do a git checkout, the index is loaded from the committed tree -- it has the SHAs of all those files and the filesystem size/times for what got written to your worktree.

When you stage aka track aka add content, that content is put into the repo and its SHA written to the index file.

`git reset --soft` doesn't touch any of that, it only changes what `HEAD` points to.  So all `git status` has to do is show you where the the index differs from the `HEAD` commit or worktree.

Comment: So when I have some files already in the index(`git add`), there are actually more in the index file(files & trees from last commit of current branch). and after I `git reset it`. those files from last commit become a visible delta by comparing to `HEAD^`. is that correct?

Comment: That's it -- no trees in the index, it's a flat list of pathnames, but other than that you've got it.